# Why isn't Anaconda working inside of one of my Conda environments while using Ubuntu LTS?

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

I'm not sure why I can't get Anaconda to launch while I'm inside of one of my Conda environments; I'm using Ubuntu LTS. While I'm in the base environment, I can run the following command in my terminal and Anaconda will start up just fine.

```
anaconda-navigator
```

I also set up a Conda environment with specifications for a specific version of python and specific versions of libraries in a .yml file; conda was able to download and install everything successfully. When I run the below command in my terminal, I can see that the environment changes.

```
conda active {environment name}
```

My problem is that when I try to start up anaconda while inside of this new environment I get a *command not found* message.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended behavior - `anaconda-navigator` is only meant to be launched from **base** environment. When **base** is not active, only the `condabin/` directory from the **base** environment is still retained on $PATH. If you really want to launch Anaconda Navigator from other environments, you could try creating a symlink/softlink pointing at the **base** `bin/anaconda-navigator`, e.g.,

```bash
conda activate base
cd $CONDA_PREFIX
ln -s bin/anaconda-navigator condabin/anaconda-navigator
```

However, this is non-standard and may lead to unexpected behavior.

Otherwise, you would need to install `anaconda-navigator` in each environment, which I don't think is recommended.

Comment: If that isn't recommended they how exactly would I launch anaconda from another environment? I pretty much just want to use spyder. Or would it make sense to just use another IDE for the other environment?

Comment: @j.jerrod.taylor try searching for `spyder-kernels`. I.e., similar to `jupyter`, one installs one copy, and launches from that environment, but then loads other environments a kernels.

Comment: See this workflow documentation for Spyder + kernel environments: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder#working-with-other-environments-and-python-installations

Comment: I tried the spyder-kernels things and it didn't really work for me, but I used a different IDE and everything worked fine.